# etracker Events via Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'd like to implement a simple form conversion event for etracker via Google Tag Manager. The event is triggered on the thank you page. I use custom html.

I tried

`_etracker.sendEvent(new et_formEvent ('formConversion', 'Registrierung'));`

And

`etForm.sendEvent('formConversion', 'Registrierung');`

Both don't work.